# Equation of progressive wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

A progressive wave traveling in positive x-direction given by $y=a\cos(kx-\omega t)$ meets a denser surface at $x=0,t=0$. The reflected wave is then given by:

I know that since the wave changes its direction of motion the sign of the equation would change and as it gets reflected from a rigid surface there will be phase change of 180 degrees. So, is the answer $y=a\cos(kx-\omega t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change in direction will be seen as a change in sign before $x$ (not whole equation which describes the amplitude of a wave).

$y=a\cos(-kx-\omega t+\pi)=-a\cos(-kx-\omega t)=-a\cos(kx+\omega t)$